# Plugin with id 'no.nils.wsdl2java' not found. Gradle

Tags: gradle, ant, wsdl2java

I have this error and I really cant understand why it is that way:

Plugin with id 'no.nils.wsdl2java' not found.

This is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "idea"
    apply plugin: "maven"
    apply plugin: "no.nils.wsdl2java"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs = [ "src" , generatedSourceWsdlDir ]
            }
            resources {
                srcDirs = [ "src" ]
            }
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        options.encoding = ENCODING
    }

    wsdl2java {
        wsdlDir = file("xml-resources")
        generatedWsdlDir = file(generatedSourceWsdlDir)
        wsdlsToGenerate = [
                ["${project.projectDir}/xml-resources/wsdl/gate/File.wsdl"]
        ]
    }

    compileJava.dependsOn(wsdl2java)
```

Comment: See https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/no.nils.wsdl2java  :  you have two ways to apply plugins:  1) using `plugins` block  2) using `apply plugin: ..` syntax. when using the second one, and if the plugin is not part of Gradle Core plugins, you need to configure the `buildscript` block as well

Comment: you should read this doc to understand the two avaible DSLs for applying plugins : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories   ( and if possible try to use the new DSL `plugins` instead of the legacy one)

Comment: It worked with plugin block. But whats the difference?

Comment: See the docs I mentioned, you'll find detailed explanation.